# Windows Azure Startup from a pre-existing MVC2 app

Tags: .net, azure, startup

I have an already existing .NET MVC2 App that, because that we are **wasting 80Gb of bandwidth per day** and I want to place it in the cloud for to be more **scalable as well cheap**.

I was looking around and **there is almost no alternative of Azure** if we are in Europe, but I already have a 700 hours account on Azure.

- I installed the latest SDK of Azure on VS2010
- I created the cloud app
- I said nothing when asked to add a role
- I manually add 2 roles selected the existing projects in the solution that I had imported before

[image]

Because I always get an error when trying to work with the certificates (even with the correct credentials it cant fetch the existing certificate on the cloud) **I compiled into a package and uploaded as production**

**Never worked!**, then I removed one and uploaded alone the "frontend" and I get the same stuff that I'm not used to and I have no idea what to do

[image]

And it's like this for almost 4 hours now:

[image]

**Can I have some help with this?** I have no one to turn to and you guys have been my best friends in my most hard programming times.***

Role is the default role

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace BackendWebRole
{
    public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("DiagnosticsConnectionString");

            // For information on handling configuration changes
            // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.
            RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;

            return base.OnStart();
        }

        private void RoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            // If a configuration setting is changing
            if (e.Changes.Any(change => change is RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange))
            {
                // Set e.Cancel to true to restart this role instance
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And **ServiceConfiguration.cscfg**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
  <Role name="Julekalender (Frontend)">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=julekal;AccountKey=xR4G1SIUTSHdvAE1IpRKPoxJRr1upJjBcdqRX2GWGkwlO6tbbu30Bikz/ApBzUKhRvk+XaozvE/NIAwDzKCg==" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <Role name="Julekalender (Backend)">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=julekal;AccountKey=xR4G1SIUTSHdvAE1IpRKPoxJRr1upJjBcdqRX2GWGkwlO6tbbu30Bikz/ApBzUKhRvk+XaozvE/NIAwDzKCg==" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

And **ServiceDefinition.csdef**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="Julekalender (Frontend)" vmsize="Medium">
    <InputEndpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </InputEndpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
  <WebRole name="Julekalender (Backend)">
    <InputEndpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="8081" />
    </InputEndpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: You really want to get your storage keys out of this website or anyone will be able to access your storage accounts!  I meant to post WebRole.cs files, not the configuration files.

Comment: keys are not valid, I changed some letter, I doubt you get to login or anything else with what's in here. ;) - but ty for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the Windows Azure MVC template, you'll need to make sure you mark the appropriate DLLs as "copy local" (because they don't exist in the cloud).  I believe these are the DLLs you need to do this with:

- System.Web.Abstractions
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing

Just go to the properties for each of these references and set "copy local" to "always."

Comment: but, if that was true, at least I could see something on the cloud, right? and then get the yellow page of death. Problem is that it never add the package to `Done`. it's always going from `Preparing node` -> `Starting role` -> `Recovering role` -> `Preparing node` -> repeat...

Comment: I did a new thing... Project > New > Cloud Service > Worker Role + MVC Role... changed the database connection to the code I have placed in the question, and it's been like this for 3 hours now: http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-12-04_0031.png Any help I would really appreciated, cause I have no idea what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance missing WebRole.cs and WebWorker.cs files in your roles?  If they have been created by Visual Studio, are they pointing to valid non-Dev-Storage account?

I don't know the new setting in v1.3 SDK, but in v1.2 SDK it was called DiagnosticsConnectionString in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file in your CloudService project

If both check out, please post your WebRole and WorkerRole files?

Comment: I do get an error on that `DiagnosticsConnectionString`, but I didnt know what was for, and their was a button `ignore & continue`. I will check this. ty.

Comment: I changed the connection string to point to the Azure Table account of mine, now I upload with no warning, but the roles dont stay. They go from `Preparing node` -> `Starting role` -> `Recovering role` -> `Preparing node` -> etc... Using Fabric on `localhost` they run ok. Any idea of what I need to do?

Comment: Can you post your Role classes?

Comment: They are the default ones, should I change? for what then? nevertheless, I add the code.

Comment: Yeah, your role class looks fine.  I would try smarx's advice regarding .DLL's.  Few people on the planet know more then him when it comes to Azure.